# How can we create OBJ property with the same name from array values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hello I'm trying to create an object that includes under the same property name a bunch of array values,
This what I'm trying

```
const quiz = [
    {question: 'Who is the main character of DBZ',
    options: ['Vegetta','Gohan','Goku']}
]

const newObj = {
    options: []
}
quiz.forEach((item)=>{
    item.options.forEach((item, index)=>{
        
    newObj.options[`name${index}`] = item
    })
})
```

expected value =

```
 newObj = {
    options: [{name: 'Vegetta'},{name:'Gohan'},{name:'Goku'}]
}
```

actual value received =

```
newObj = {
  { options: [ name0: 'Vegetta', name1: 'Gohan', name2: 'Goku' ] }}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `newObj.options.push({name: item})` instead of ` newObj.options[`name${index}`] = item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, `` newObj.options[`name${index}`] = item `` creates a new key on your `options` array, and sets that to `item`. You instead want to push an object of the form `{name: item}` into your array. There are a few ways you could go about this, one way is to use [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) like so:

```js
quiz.forEach((item)=>{
  item.options.forEach((item)=>{
    newObj.options.push({name: item});
  })
});
```

while not as common, you can also use set the current index of `options`, which is slightly different to the above example, as it will maintain the same index, which can be important if `quiz` is a sparse array that you want to keep the same indexing of on `options`:

```js
quiz.forEach((item)=>{
  item.options.forEach((item, index)=>{
    newObj.options[index] = {name: item};
  })
});
```

Example of the difference:

```js
const arr = [1, 2,,,5]; // sparse array
const pushRes = [];
const indxRes = [];

arr.forEach(n => pushRes.push(n));
arr.forEach((n, i) => indxRes[i] = n);
console.log("Push result", pushRes);
console.log("Index result", indxRes);
```

---

For a different approach, you also have the option of using something like [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create your `options` array, which you can use to create `newObj`:

```js
const quiz = [
  {question: 'Who is the main character of DBZ',
    options: ['Vegetta','Gohan','Goku']}
];

const options = quiz.flatMap(({options}) => options.map(name => ({name})));
const newObj = {options};
console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly man Thank you so much! you also gave a good explanation, Have a good one!